# Problem with subtype usage in concurrent Ada program

Tags: concurrency, task, ada, subtype

I am working on a concurrent programming problem in Ada. The task is to simulate a bridge over which different cars can pass from different directions. The complication lies in the fact that, if an ambulance is present, the cars must give it absolute priority.

Here is the code I have developed:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   type Direccion is (Norte, Sur);

   task type Vehiculo (ID : Integer; Acceso : Direccion);
   task type Ambulancia;

   protected type Puente is
      entry Entrar (ID : Integer; Acceso : Direccion);
      entry Salir (ID : Integer);
   private
      Puente_Ocupado : Boolean := False;
      Ambulancia_Esperando : Boolean := False;
      Ambulancia_En_Puente : Boolean := False;
      Coches_En_Espera : Integer := 0;
      Ambulancia_En_Espera : Boolean := False;

      procedure Entrar_Ambulancia;
      procedure Entrar_Coche(ID : Integer; Acceso : Direccion);
   end Puente;

   task body Vehiculo is
   begin
      Put_Line ("El coche" & Integer'Image(ID) & " está en ruta en dirección " & Direccion'Image(Acceso) & "!");

      Puente.Entrar(ID, Acceso);
      delay(1.0); -- Simula el tiempo que tarda en cruzar el puente
      Puente.Salir(ID);
   end Vehiculo;

   task body Ambulancia is
   begin
      Put_Line ("La ambulancia 112 está en ruta");
      Puente.Entrar(112, Norte); -- Cambiado a un acceso específico, puedes ajustar según tus necesidades
      delay(0.5); -- Simula el tiempo que tarda en cruzar el puente
      Puente.Salir(112);
   end Ambulancia;

   protected body Puente is
      entry Entrar (ID : Integer; Acceso : Direccion) when not Puente_Ocupado is
      begin
         if ID = 112 then
            Entrar_Ambulancia;
         else
            Entrar_Coche(ID, Acceso);
         end if;
      end Entrar;

      entry Salir (ID : Integer) when Puente_Ocupado is
      begin
         if ID = 112 then
            Ambulancia_En_Puente := False;
         else
            Puente_Ocupado := False;
            Coches_En_Espera := 0;
         end if;
      end Salir;

      procedure Entrar_Ambulancia is
      begin
         if Puente_Ocupado then
            Ambulancia_Esperando := True;
            Ambulancia_En_Espera := True;
            Put_Line ("+++++Ambulancia 112 espera para entrar");
         else
            Puente_Ocupado := True;
            Ambulancia_En_Puente := True;
            Put_Line ("+++++Ambulancia 112 está en el puente");
         end if;
      end Entrar_Ambulancia;

      procedure Entrar_Coche(ID : Integer; Acceso : Direccion) is
      begin
         if Puente_Ocupado or Ambulancia_En_Puente then
            Coches_En_Espera := Coches_En_Espera + 1;
            Put_Line ("El coche" & Integer'Image(ID) & " espera a la entrada " & Direccion'Image(Acceso) & ". Esperan " & Integer'Image(Coches_En_Espera) & " coches.");
         else
            Puente_Ocupado := True;
            Put_Line ("El coche" & Integer'Image(ID) & " entra en el puente. Esperan en la " & Direccion'Image(Acceso) & ": " & Integer'Image(Coches_En_Espera) & " coches.");
         end if;
      end Entrar_Coche;
   end Puente;
   
   -- Creación de instancias
   Coche1 : Vehiculo(1, Norte);
   Coche2 : Vehiculo(2, Sur);
   Coche3 : Vehiculo(3, Norte);
   Coche4 : Vehiculo(4, Sur);
   Coche5 : Vehiculo(5, Norte);
   Amb : Ambulancia;
   
begin   
   -- Esperar la finalización de los procesos
   while not (Coche1'Terminated and Coche2'Terminated and Coche3'Terminated and Coche4'Terminated and Coche5'Terminated and Amb'Terminated) loop
      null;
   end loop;

   -- Mensajes finales
      Put_Line("Todos los vehículos han cruzado el puente y la ambulancia ha completado su ruta.");
end Main;
```

The current code generates errors indicating "invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call". I am using subtypes to represent directions (North, South), "(Norte, Sur)", and there seems to be a problem when trying to use them in certain expressions or calls.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to fix this problem and any suggestions on how to improve the efficiency or clarity of the code.

Compiler Error:

```
main.adb:27:7: error: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
main.adb:29:7: error: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
main.adb:35:7: error: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
main.adb:37:7: error: invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
```

- I have tried to review the Ada documentation, but I have not been able to identify the specific problem in my code.
- I am using subtypes to represent addresses, and I suspect the error might be related to their use in procedure calls within tasks.
  Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the use of `Puente` within the body of the tasks.

The definition `protected type Puente is` creates a type called `Puente`.
Maybe you meant to create a protected object instead, like so `protected Puente is`?

Inside type definitions (like `Puente`), the name of the type refers to the current instance (object) of the type, which is the reason you don't get similar errors in the body of `Puente`